# The Fed Lowered Interest Rates, Are they going to buy Bonds?

Tags: interest-rate, economics, federal-reserve

The Fed just lowered interest rates yesterday by 0.25%.
I haven't heard anyone mentioning a resurgence of quantitative easing (QE).

Are they buying bonds in order to influence the interest rate?  If so, where can we find the dollar amount of bonds they are buying and over what time frame?

Comment: I disagree that this is off-topic, because QE, interest rates, etc all affect Personal Finance.

Comment: These are two separate issues.  The Fed  funds rate is  rate at which depository institutions lend  other depository institutions overnight.  Quantitative easing is where the Fed purchases bonds or other securities  to increase the money supply and encourage lending.  Also, agree that this question is not off topic.

Comment: @BobBaerker The Fed does not directly control rates.  It does so through open market operations.  I don't believe they are separate issues.

Comment: The Fed  funds rate influences the rates offered by banks and credit institutions to businesses and consumers and has a direct effect on the economy.  It does not change the money supply which QE does.

Comment: @BobBaerker The Fed sets a target Fed funds rate.  They do not have direct control over it.  They try to influence that rate through open market operations - which is their most popular option - and other strategies.  I'm not sure you understand the topic in question or maybe I am misunderstanding what you are trying to say.

Comment: While potentially on-topic here, asking this on economics.SE may also get answers.

Comment: https://www.nytimes.com/2019/09/18/business/fed-repo-rates.html